# Typescript - infer generic type from object prop value

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I read a lot, and found similar things but not exactly what I want.

I want to define a type by using a prop value inside an object and use that information to define other property inside this object.

JSX.IntrinsicElements includes definitions for all react elements. let's focus on the SVG elements `circle` and `path` for this example.

so lets try define the type defention:

```js
export type svgCustomType<T extends "path" | "circle"> = {
  svgElem: T;
  svgProps?: { [key in keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements[T]]: JSX.IntrinsicElements[T] };
};
```

here I try to get the type value T(which can be "path" or "circle") and use this value to define the appropriate properties type for `svgProps`.(can be `React.SVGProps<SVGCircleElement>` or `React.SVGProps<SVGPathElement>`

example usage:

```js
const test: svgCustomType = {  //Error: "Generic type 'svgCustomType' requires 1 type argument(s)", why?
  svgElem: "path",
  svgProps: {
    cx: 10,  // next step: should be error here because cx is not defined in `SVGPathElement`
  },
};
```

Why do I get `Generic type 'svgCustomType' requires 1 type argument(s)`? I want to get this type from `svgElem` value.

i will just mention that using `const test: svgCustomType<"path"> = {...}` will work and `cx` will not be accepted.

**for clearly**:
I'm not sure if is even possible in typescript.
I'm writing a [react lib](https://github.com/Eliav2/react-xarrows) and i want my user to be able to get IntelliSense suggestions while typing,and if the user running typescript(and not javascript) he will also will get type errors.
let's say my lib component have prop `svgHeadProp` with type `svgCustomType`.
so i want the user to be able to write:

```
svgHeadProp={svgElem:"path",svgProps:{...}}
```

and not:

```
svgHeadProp<"path">={svgElem:"path",svgProps:{...}}
```

because not all my users uses typescript(and for the ones that does, its annoying specifying type for a prop )

Comment: There's a solution to get the types to match, but it won't give the error on `cx`, as `React.SVGProps<SVGPathElement>` does have a `cx` property for some reason (https://tsplay.dev/WoqolN).

Comment: (The reason you get an error for `svgCustomType<"path">` is that because of the `svgProps` typing, you need to use `svgProps: {cx: {cx: 10}}`, which is accepted for both paths and circles.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The issue is that to use `SvgCustomTypeGeneric` in a type signature, you'll have to pass that type parameter.  Using `SvgCustomTypeGeneric<'path' | 'circle'>` won't work, as this will just allow every occurrence of `T` to be `'path'` or `'circle'` without any dependency between them. What will work though is a union type, `SvgCustomTypeGeneric<'path'> | SvgCustomTypeGeneric<'circle'>`, which can be created from the `'path' | 'circle'` union.

To show how it works, let's rename the generic function to `SvgCustomTypeGeneric`, and use `JSX.IntrinsicElements[T]` as the type of `svgProps` (otherwise the values are nested, e.g. `svgProps: cx: {cx: 10})`):

```
type SvgKey = 'path' | 'circle'

export type SvgCustomTypeGeneric<T extends SvgKey> = {
  svgElem: T;
  svgProps?: JSX.IntrinsicElements[T]
}
```

To create a union type of `SvgCustomTypeGeneric` types, you can use a mapped type to create an object with for each key the corresponding `SvgCustomTypeGeneric` type, and extract the values from this:

```
type SvgCustomType = {[K in SvgKey]: SvgCustomTypeGeneric<K>}[SvgKey]
//  evaluates to: SvgCustomTypeGeneric<"path"> | SvgCustomTypeGeneric<"circle">
```

When testing it, the `cx` property is not helpful as it is also allowed on an `SVGPathElement`, but the `ref` property requires a correctly typed value, and can be used instead:

```
const test: SvgCustomType[] = [{
    svgElem: 'path',
    svgProps: {
      cx: 10, // No error, SVGPathElement can have 'cx' properties.
      ref: createRef<SVGPathElement>(),
    },
  }, {
    svgElem: 'circle',
    svgProps: {
      cx: 10,
      ref: createRef<SVGCircleElement>(),
    },
  }, { // ERROR
    svgElem: 'circle',
    svgProps: {
      cx: 10,
      ref: createRef<SVGPathElement>(),
    },
  },
]
```

An alternative solution is to create a generic constructor function to validate the objects. It's a bit simpler and gives prettier error messages, but does require adding actual code rather than just types:

```
const mkSvg =<K extends SvgKey>(x: SvgCustomTypeGeneric<K>) => x

const test = mkSvg({
  svgElem: 'circle',
  svgProps: {
    ref: createRef<SVGPathElement>(),
    // Type 'RefObject<SVGPathElement>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<SVGCircleElement> 
  },
})
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYygUwIYzQJTQMzgF858oIQ4BydDZGKgWACgWYBPMNOAZQDcA5gGk07OAF5qYLAAsqcAD7VkwKMgA2aJq2ZoAHpFhwOXXoIDCAVwDOMCgBVOaAOJoAdmijBkAHntx9bDcAE2szYVEAPglEFjg4a0EAUU0QAC44ewBuOITBAAVyMGsAfgyAKR4ADQA6AEk3GC83a28UtBB3GGsAbXsAXRYiFjYncKtbBzHJBB6hOGA3cJF2foz%20AQm7EEcuVw8vXyFIoh6NlcHmAHor%20LQ%20DHVLLDQwu3WLG23dl3dPbx8ACJpDAZIDokoNlspns-ocgSo1JpwSMdMgIC14NhbABGD6bL4wtA9foxHoIXLxRICdrpKSyKgAGkpeQEhQgxQyFOY8V5KD0GRxAAZGXAbnAAHIQAJQchQUU8ABqznyslpXRQGCWMgwfG4VGQenkYCKnhgwFeNRZ8XQ%20AyqEw2Dw%20B8SpVatSXUiAAoAJTMnm8ogB%20LB2KBqnJVIZA2qDRaEO86nsznhvnxQ2CkXWuC2%2020J0EV3K8xxzTqxo%20-0s4O5MNIcVJHA4ADyOBZ1NpMcR8aZHYKRWsXJzmbgwsTfLzKALuCLbtVoIrMCrE%20IidrzEuLHRmLgIAA1hsJD55oF3KFllFvQLxoSdk59v8jpFfRJonpUTvbMZXjAAEwxAeGzetykY0tGyhlgmuTJoOw4RrmBD5o6s4uvOHodF6fqruKPzUM6LYAEYAFZoPQxbuounqVvIwBhG4EDwBg1itAIbgYIRmjGNKJj6gAMmgAh0OwzoUaWSJoEu0R1gGRC%20iwQA)

UPDATE: It's also possible to write `SvgCustomType` as a one-liner, by using conditional types to introduce the type variable and distribute it over the union:

```
export type SvgCustomTypeOneLiner =
  SvgKey extends infer T ? T extends SvgKey ? {
    svgElem: T;
    svgProps?: JSX.IntrinsicElements[T]
  } : never : never
```

And if you really want to go all out, you can even drop the dependency on `SvgKey`:

```
type SvgCustomTypeUltimate = 
  keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements extends infer T ? T extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements ? {
    svgElem: T;
    svgProps?: JSX.IntrinsicElements[T]
  } : never : never
```

Both these types have the same behavior as `SvgCustomType` defined above.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYygUwIYzQJTQMzgF858oIQ4BydDZGKgWACgWYBPMNOAZQDcA5gGk07OAF5qYLAAsqcAD7VkwKMgA2aJq2ZoAHpFhwOXXoIDCAVwDOMCgBVOaAPIA7NABlg7qBJZwzYVE4fWxXABNrOG98NF97OAB+OATQtAio-iCxZIR-ALhrQQBRTRAALhSAbnyAooEABXIwa0TKgCkeAA0AOgBJVxgob2tgZFK0EHSYawBtewBdfJJK9z44uFW0dagWFmQIV1tjNFsARkqsq1sHJzdPbzjZhYk4WbzmAsKSssqqaRgcgANLVvo1mtZKh8vgFkHpKmcAAxAuAAelRcAAchAQlByFAUTwAGoAcQasgmU0GKAwrjgMgw62UenkYGacRgwFOPVBAXQ+EqqEw2Dw+AAPMSyRSytMAHwACgAlCDPgUiCqAurEKD6pS-io1JoqBqCvUmhAWlDeSh4XAkSavvzBbQRQQJaTzKoNGhKXKlQ7iCatUh0XBijgcM4cDqfpN9V6jQGzRCraqvnCEcjrU6UC7cG7JeTAb7BgrlaD1csVUsdPpDPATNwrjY7CBHFwAKrqTkgLDcST5ADWogghE6vQGQxGYxLMxCejCkWirli8SSKXni6iw-Yo7g4-6g2GRxnMsGUVyMYEeuqV-NLTa++6h6nJ-GZ5m8xrms2cDWGy2HY9mYA4jgbU4YAAJkuCwW1uTtu1APtnled4rxvf5ZGNO8U21NMCgzO1kTRDFsVxfFCVJIsZFnGk6QZJkqDhVl2VgLlrB5fC+QIZ1hXzcVC2lSY-XLfDK1VYN0N+ZQEy0JNBHvSE8JhG1MwDbiBVzPjRXdElPUNH0PzLANxM1FEQwxcNI2jfDdWkpjZOw2yFNw6EYUI+1sx4rS+x0wTiyM-0KyDasWCAA)

Comment: just a great answer! this is what I've been looking for! thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome :-) About the one-liner, it's possible but not pretty. Let me add it to the answer.

Comment: great update friend! wish I could vote up twice!

Comment: this is like magic (in a good way)

Comment: Say you would like to have an object type in place of `SVGKey`, how would you approach that? This fails with the union type, as only `string | number | symbol` are allowed as property keys.